# Use signal handler to return from a function

Tags: c, linux, operating-system, signals

Is it possible to write a signal handler that forces the program to return from a function?

For example, in the following code:

```
void myfun() {
    __asm__("repeat: jmp repeat");
}
```

myfun() has an indefinite loop. I would like to stop this indefinite loop and return to main function by raising some signal. Is this possible?

Thanks.

Comment: [`man setjmp`](http://linux.die.net/man/3/setjmp)

Answer (score 1):

Inside the signal handler perform a `longjmp` to a `setjmp` prepared in `main`.

Comment: In the given assembly code, no volatile variable is being checked. I am using it to profile processor performance for branch instructions, and so interference from other variables should be minimal. Ideally, I would like to raise an exception that allows the function to return.

Comment: @Arani I checked the standard and I don't see any provision that forbids you to call the `longjmp` directly from the handler and then the loop doesn't have to be changed. I'll change my answer accordingly.